# Syntax Error Missing Operator VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I have a `Dlookup` in Access 2010 that's supposed to pull a value from a query table that counts the number of checkboxes untoggled. When I run it, it gives me a 'Missing operator in query expression' here.

```
Countboxes = DLookup("Expr1", "qryCountUntoggled", "[ProjNo =]" & Me.ProjNo & "'")
```

I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Move the `=` outside the `]`. As it is now, if `Me.ProjNo` is 5, your expression is `[ProjNo =] 5`, which clearly isn't what you want. I'm suspecting it should be `"[ProjNo] = '" & Me.ProjNo & "'"`.

Comment: Set a break point on that line and run the code.  When it goes into break mode, test the `DLookup` expression with Ken's suggested changes in the Immediate window: `? DLookup("Expr1", "qryCountUntoggled", "[ProjNo] = '" & Me.ProjNo & "'")`  That looks correct to me, but you'll know for sure if Access gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ProjNo is numeric, the correct code is:

```
Countboxes = DLookup("Expr1", "qryCountUntoggled", "[ProjNo] =" & Me.ProjNo )
```

If ProjNo is text, the code should be:

```
Countboxes = DLookup("Expr1", "qryCountUntoggled", "[ProjNo] ='" & Me.ProjNo & "'")
```